# How to take a screenshot of the page with html2canvas using beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to snap a page and post its canvas.toDataURL result to an external server. Everything works great, but I need to take a screenshot right before a visitor leaves the page (most often after submitting a form). What I do is add a handler for ***beforeunload*** event using JQ like so:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {async: true, logging: true}).then(function(canvas){
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'apiurl.php',
            data: {"screenshot":data},
            success: function(){},
            async:true
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is *html2canvas* is asynchronous and its async flag, whether set to true or false, does not change its behavior. There does not seem to be a native way to make *html2canvas* take screenshots synchronously. So the page does not wait for it to execute and just lets the visitor leave and thus *html2canvas* and *$.ajax* inside it do not have a chance to properly complete.

And even if I make the *$.ajax* post synchronous, it still does not solve the problem, because the original call *html2canvas* is still asynchronous.

How do I make the page wait for *html2canvas* and *$.ajax* to finish? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you'd even be able to send this image to the server? The only solid way to make a request to a server in onunload is [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon), and while I'm not entirely sure of the limits (might be user-agent dependent), I think it can't exceed 64KiB [as defined here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-or-cache-fetch). You'd be stuck anyway. Can't you block whatever will unload the page until all this process is done instead? (Should be doable at least for your <form>, if you replace it with AJAX).

Comment: Ps: `async:true` is the default for h2c, should be `async:false` for your use-case

Comment: As stated in the post, async:false doesn't seem to do anything. I know the option exists, but it doesn't work.